# Function only executes after some time (video Load)

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a very simple webpage I have a video in the background autoplaying and some jquery script to load html content in a div. Strangely enough he javascript function on the links only executes after 12 seconds or so. I think it has to do with the video load as when i replace the video with an image it works properly. Any help appreciated towards solving this. Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Breathing Room</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="abstract">Abstract</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="chi2018">CHI2018</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="links">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content">
        Start text here.
    </div>
        <div class="video-bg">
            <video autoplay loop muted poster="_images/background.jpg">
                <source src="_images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and javascript:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
    $("#abstract").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("../pages/abstract.html");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add `autoplay` to `video` tag. You can put video play in `$(document).ready`

```
<video loop muted poster="_images/background.jpg">
    <source src="_images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

$(document).ready( function() {
    document.getElementByTag('video').play();
    $("#abstract").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("../pages/abstract.html");
    });
});
```

Hope this help